# Is there anyway to block blob requests in Chrome from a website?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here's the situation, I want to block some blob requests by using extensions, and I tried to use Adblock and Requestly, but they don't work.

And in fact, Chrome can do this trick by "Block request domain", just like this:

[image]
[image]

But it only works on current tab, so is there anyway to block specific blob requests from a website?

Comment: `blob` isn't reported via webRequest, see https://crbug.com/872297, so you'd have to override XMLHttpRequest/fetch in the page context using xhook library or [manually](https://medium.com/better-programming/chrome-extension-intercepting-and-reading-the-body-of-http-requests-dd9ebdf2348b?).

Comment: @McGrady Requestly & Adblock both rely on WebRequest API for blocking requests and since blob is not intercepted, both the extensions do not work.